# Render EditorTemplates based on authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Is it possible to render the editortemplates if a user is logged on and the displaytemplates as a default or do I need to create my own Html helper extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a custom helper method for this:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static MvcHtmlString MyHelper<TModel, TValue>(
        this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, 
        Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression
    )
    {
        if (htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return htmlHelper.EditorFor(expression);
        }
        return htmlHelper.DisplayFor(expression);
    }
}
```

And use:

```
<%: Html.MyHelper(x => x.SomeValue) %>
```